# How to make rake work when bundle is incomplete (not all gems are installed successfully)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundle

I have a gem that does not install properly (probably due to system incompatabilities). Each time I call rake, it returns "cound not find *rmagic* in any of the sources. run bundle install".

I want push the app to Heroku later. But I have some database to seed first. Is it possible to force rake to go with tasks anyway, despite of the missing gem and without installing it?

Comment: you can temporary remove "bad" gems from gemfile, but that's bad solution. as developer you should work in linux or, at least, have linux running on some vbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this possible? Yes, you can disable bundler by removing the lines that look like this in your config/application.rb

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

I do not recommend this, as you'll need to start gem/dependency management on your own. But, it might be enough to get rake to load and work for you, provided you don't need to actually run any code.

I highly recommend you just install image-magick and then rmagick. http://www.imagemagick.org/